# Algebraic Topology pamphlets?

Tags: algebraic-topology, self-learning

I'm looking to self-learn some Algebraic Topology and have found the books I've looked at so far (ie. Hatcher) to be rather tome-like for my tastes. Does anyone know of a good slim lecture notes style book (or, indeed, an actual set of lecture notes) I can have a look at?

I need to catch up on the Cambridge part II course (I foolishly dropped it about half way through before realising the following term that I actually quite liked Geometry) for which the syllabus is as follows

> The fundamental group
>
> > Homotopy of continuous functions and homotopy equivalence between topological spaces. The fundamental
> >     group of a space, homomorphisms induced by maps of spaces, change of base point, invariance
> >     under homotopy equivalence.
>
> Covering spaces
>
> > Covering spaces and covering maps. Path-lifting and homotopy-lifting properties, and ther application
> >     to the calculation of fundamental groups. The fundamental group of the circle; topological proof of the
> >     fundamental theorem of algebra. *Construction of the universal covering of a path-connected, locally
> >     simply connected space*. The correspondence between connected coverings of X and conjugacy classes
> >     of subgroups of the fundamental group of X.
>
> The Seifert–Van Kampen theorem
>
> > Free groups, generators and relations for groups, free products with amalgamation. Statement *and
> >     proof* of the Seifert–Van Kampen theorem. Applications to the calculation of fundamental groups.
>
> Simplicial complexes
>
> > Finite simplicial complexes and subdivisions; the simplicial approximation theorem.
>
> Homology
>
> > Simplicial homology, the homology groups of a simplex and its boundary. Functorial properties for
> >     simplicial maps. *Proof of functoriality for continuous maps, and of homotopy invariance*.
>
> Homology calculations
>
> > The homology groups of Sn, applications including Brouwer’s fixed-point theorem. The Mayer-Vietoris
> >     theorem. *Sketch of the classification of closed combinatorical surfaces*; determination of their homology
> >     groups. Rational homology groups; the Euler–Poincar´e characteristic and the Lefschetz fixed-point
> >     theorem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/notes/ has the notes from our year.

Comment: This is great, thanks

Answer (score 5):

http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/pamphlets/algtop.pdf

http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr44.pdf

Answer (score 3):

My book [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) is  one of few at this level to give an account of  the van Kampen theorem with lots of applications (cell complexes, knots, Jordan Curve Theorem) and of covering spaces, both in terms of **fundamental groupoids**. (You also get orbit spaces, which you won't find elsewhere in English.) A pdf is available through the above web page.

A proof of a  general  version of the van Kampen theorem for the fundamental groupoid on a set of base points and a union of many open sets is available [here](http://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/brown-razak.pdf)  (the proof is no harder than doing it for one base point!)

The pushout version for a union of two sets with two base points allows the computation of the fundamental group of the circle,  which is, after all, THE basic example in algebraic topology. For that example, one base point is not enough, but two will do.

See also this [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one) link for more discussion on several base points; this image

[image: union]

shows a union of 3 spaces which requires $8$ base points to encapsulate the symmetry information.

Comment: Ronnie's book is now available for free, just scroll down the linked page a bit.

Comment: My answer has been updated.